# Error: The argument type 'String' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Uri'. - 'Uri' is from 'dart:core'

Tags: android, string, flutter, localhost, uri

i have Problem with this error:

```
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:inboxed/model/login_model.dart';

class APIService {
  Future<LoginResponseModel> login(LoginRequestModel requestModel) async {
    String url = 'https://localhost:3000/api/users/session';

    final response = await http.post(url, body: requestModel.toJson());
    if (response.statusCode == 200 || response.statusCode == 400) {
      return LoginResponseModel.fromJson(
        json.decode(response.body),
      );
    } else {
      throw Exception('Failed to load Data');
    }
  }
}
```

Debugging Console:

Launching lib\main.dart on AOSP on IA Emulator in debug mode...

lib/api/api_service.dart:10:38: Error: The argument type 'String' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Uri'.

Uri' is from 'dart:core'.
final response = await http.post(url, body: requestModel.toJson());

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

Where:
Script 'C:\development\flutter\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\flutter.gradle' line: 991

What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'.
Process 'command 'C:\development\flutter\bin\flutter.bat'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 38s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
Exited (sigterm)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just parse the String url with a Uri....
See the example below

```
String url = "your_endpoint_here";
final response = await http.post(Uri.parse(url), body: requestModel.toJson());
```

Answer (score 0):

Need to parse your url with below code and pass this instead of url string;

```
Uri.parse(url)
```

*A sample code of usage* ;

```
String url = "https://sandbox-api.iyzipay.com/payment/bin/check";
  Map body = {"locale":"tr","conversationId":"123456ayx5","binNumber":"$binNumber"} ;

  //String 
  String requeststr = "locale=tr,conversationId=123456ayx5,binNumber=$binNumber";

  String pkistring = v1hashing(requeststr);

  HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();
  HttpClientRequest request = await httpClient.postUrl(Uri.parse(url));

//headers
  request.headers.set('Accept' ,  'application/json');
  request.headers.set('Content-Type' ,  'application/json');


//body
  request.add(utf8.encode(json.encode(body)));

//response 
  HttpClientResponse response = await request.close();
  print(response.statusCode); 
  String reply = await response.transform(utf8.decoder).join();
  Map responseMap = json.decode(reply);
  httpClient.close();
  print(responseMap);
```